# the sequence does not have elements executing linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4.1

Having this model class

```
public class Usuario
{
    #region Atributos
    private int _intID = 0;
    private Perfil _Perfil_FK = null;
    private String _strNombre = "";
    private String _strPassword = "";
    #endregion

    #region Propiedades
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _intID; }
        set { _intID = value; }
    }
    public virtual Perfil Perfil_FK
    {
        get { return _Perfil_FK; }
        set { _Perfil_FK = value; }
    }
    public int PerfilID { get; set; }
    public String Nombre
    {
        get { return _strNombre; }
        set { _strNombre = value; }
    }
    public String Password
    {
        get { return _strPassword; }
        set { _strPassword = value; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I'm trying to use this query, the data base table have data, so i can't see the problem?

```
 Usuario user = (from U in _db.Usuario
                            where ((U.Nombre == model.UserName) && (U.Password == encripPassword))
                            select U).First();
```

If you need more info about the data base let me know to update my question

Comment: Does the table actually have a row with that name and password? When you run the generated SQL statement in SQL Management Studio, do you get a result?

Comment: @p.campbell Yes, it bringing me results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Does the table actually have a row with that name and password?
- When you run the generated SQL statement in SQL Management Studio, do you get a result?

Suggest checking your two values in UserName and encripPassword for valid values.

```
Usuario user = _db.Usuario
                  .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Nombre == model.UserName
                                 &&  x.Password == encripPassword);

string sql = (user as ObjectQuery).ToTraceString(); //the SQL query generated.

if(user==null)
{
  //doesn't exist.
}
```

Comment: The data base table have a `Nombre` and a `password` columns

Comment: Yes the table has the columns, but does it have a record with the specific values for those columns that you're looking for?  The First() LINQ extension method with throw an exception if no rows are returned, regardless of the columns being correct...

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you're not pointing to the right database, or your don't have a user name with that password (I'm guessing the encrypted password doesn't match what's in the DB.  Try using FirstOrDefault(), then you can check for Null if the password is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Check if your class has the proper attributes that tell Linq to SQL how to match it against a database table.

Your class should have

```
[Table(Name="Nombres")]
```

attribute, and properties should have

```
[Column]
```

attributes, some should also be primary keys etc.

If you don't already have this, I suggest you generate the class using the Entity Class Generation tool: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx#linqtosql_topic32